# Query rows with most recent time stamp in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, duplicates, unique, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have some data in Google Sheets that contains duplicate account numbers with different dates. I want to query the data and to remove the duplicates, and select only those rows with the most recent date.

Sample data is here:

```
115684  11/21/2019  Blue
115684  11/20/2019  Green
115684  11/19/2019  Yellow
165488  11/17/2019  Red
165488  11/12/2019  Blue
165488  6/19/2019   Green
556689  11/21/2019  Yellow
556690  11/21/2019  Red
556691  6/19/2019   Blue
```

so the result should look like this:

```
115684  11/21/2019  Blue
165488  11/17/2019  Red
556689  11/21/2019  Yellow
556690  11/21/2019  Red
556691  6/19/2019   Blue
```

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
=QUERY(A:C, "SELECT A, B, C WHERE MAX(B)")
```

Comment: I ended up using this:

Comment: =SORTN(SORT(A:C,2,0), 999999999, 2, 1, 0) which is the same as player0 suggested with a slight modification to the column selection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=SORTN(SORT(A1:C, 2, 0), 99^99, 2, 2, 0)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hey thanks for the prompt reply. i hadn't considering the sortn function. works great.